# Where can I put laravel 4 filter classes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In laravel 4, you can create filter classes instead of putting the entire filter inside a closure -- great. But do these filters have to be entirely in the `app/filters.php` or `app/routes.php`?

Generally I like to do one file per class, but I imagine there's something better to do then a bunch of includes in the filters.php file. Where would you put these for laravel to find them automatically? For example:

```
Route::filter('Thing', 'ThingFilter');

# can I put this in its own file and have laravel automatically use it?
class ThingFilter {
    function filter() { ... }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a default to my knowledge, but you can call `ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(app_path().'/filters'));` to register your filter directory.

Comment: The most likely place to put that is probably in `start/{$env}.php`, so for instance `start/production.php`.

Comment: put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :) Thank you!

Comment: In Laravel 4 you have composer's autoloader. You can create a class under `model` and type its name name in the filter like: `Route::filter('Thing', 'ThingFilter')`. Remember always do a composer dump-autoload first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a default to my knowledge, but you can call `ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(app_path().'/filters'));` to register your filter directory. The correct place to put that is in **`app/start/global.php`** where you should see some folders already being registered.

There is a 'local.php' which *seems* a candidate, but this is only meant for specific environments (usually development, provided you add a proper array or closure in `$app->detectEnvironment()`).

Answer (score 16):

I've all my filters in a separate directory called **filters**.
And here's how my filters.php file look like...

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
// Route Filters
//---------------------------------------------------------
Route::filter('auth', 'AuthFilter@default');
Route::filter('auth.basic', 'AuthFilter@basic');
Route::filter('guest', 'AuthFilter@guest');
Route::filter('csrf', 'CsrfFilter');
```

I autoload them via **composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/filters",
        "app/presenters",
        "app/repositories",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

After you update your composer.json file, you need to run the command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

To verfiy that you files will be loaded, check out

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```